# How do I modify this sending email code to expand the range to multiple columns?

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to send emails from a spreadsheet to multiple people but only email them the information in all the columns and not just 1. For example, I want all the information from B2:E2 to be emailed to A2.

I am using the basic template provided in the Google Support which I have attached below.

All the changes to the code that I have made have not worked:

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 2;   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
    var message = row[1];       // Second column
    var subject = "Sending emails from a Spreadsheet";
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

Comment: What changes have you tried? Your question is too broad at the moment

Answer (score 1):

There are quite few changes to make to the original script, html is our friend in this context, it will look nicer.

code :

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 2;   // Number of rows to process
  var colWidth = 5; // column width, including first one
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:E3, one email per row
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, colWidth)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var subject = "Sending emails from a Spreadsheet";
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
    var message = '<body><div style="font-family:arial,sans;font-size:10pt"><p>welcome message</p>';  
    message+= '<table style="border-collapse:collapse;" border = 1 cellpadding = 4><tr>';
    for(var n=1 ; n<row.length ; n++){
      message += '<td bgcolor="#EEF">'+row[n]+'</td>'
    }
    message += '</tr></table></div></body>';  
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, 'html only',{htmlBody:message});
  }
}
```

Sheet example :

[image]

email result , third row :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have set up a spreadsheet which I think mimics the table structure you are looking for:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1S3fWaV4Sl4mIYjT-kMtOlP2V4xWSOpz721bxGWFuNqQ/edit

And the following function sends out emails:

- One email per row
- Email address in column 0, data in the other columns

Code:

```
// The range of data including email columns
// Example is set up with email in Column A, data in B and C
// Headers on Row 1, data rows on 2 and 3.
var DATA_RANGE = 'A2:C3';

function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getRange(DATA_RANGE);
  var values = data.getValues();

  for (var i = 0, row; row = values[i]; i++) {
    // Take email address from column A
    var emailAddress = row[0];
    // Join the remaining columns, comma-separated (as an example)
    var messageData = row.slice(1).join(', ');
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, 'Sending emails from a Spreadsheet', messageData);
  }
}
```

Does this cover what you're trying to do?